# TCP Client does not receive data from all client but only one

Tags: c#, tcplistener

So I tried to receive all data from every single client but for some reason, it only want to receive data from one client (random) and does not want to receive data from other client so what am I doing wrong?

Code where backgroundworker will register each client to its own new backgroundworker:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                client = network.AcceptTcpClient();
                streamer = client.GetStream();
                worker.ReportProgress(0,"Client Accepted");
                buffers = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                comboBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
comboBox1.Items.Add(client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "_" + 
client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString()); }));
                listConnectedClients.Add(client);
                BackgroundWorker theworker = new BackgroundWorker();
                theworker.DoWork += bgwhelper(client);
                theworker.RunWorkerAsync();
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Client Connection Error");
                client.Close();
                streamer.Close();
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Code where it handles each client's response data:

```
public DoWorkEventHandler bgwhelper(TcpClient mainclients)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream mainsteams = mainclients.GetStream();
            int databases = mainsteams.Read(buffers, 0, buffers.Length);
            string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffers, 0, databases);
            if (data == "cmd1")
            {
                byte[] datacen = new byte[mainclients.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int main = mainsteams.Read(datacen, 0, datacen.Length);
                var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(datacen, 0, main);
                MessageBox.Show(message, 
mainclients.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "_" + 
mainclients.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "'s Response");
            } else if (data == "cmd2")
            {

            }
        } catch(Exception)
        {
            removeclient(mainclients);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how you are using `client` but due to this line of code `client = network.AcceptTcpClient();`, it will always contain the most recently created client.

Comment: oh ok, i though the code will just pause there until a new client connects then continues the code but any solution that would help solve that?

Comment: See the msdn examples for sockets.  The code uses sockets but you can usvbsititue for any class that inherits the socket class like TCLListener class

Comment: Yes it will pause there, but after the pause `client` will have a reference to the newly created one. Again, I am not sure how you use the `client`. It may give you issues, or it may not; depending on the usage.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i basically when a client connects, it will store it on the List and then cretate a new backgroundworker and let it read loop to read through all the client's data response

Comment: If you do not need it anywhere else, then make `client` a local variable. Right now it is a class level variable, and thus makes no sense.